# Realizing and Retrieving information from a producer-consumer OWL model

Tags: sparql, owl, semantic-web, linked-data, shacl

I have the following scenario modelled in OWL:

`Producer` `----producesResource--->` `Resource` `<------consumesResource ----` `Consumer`

`Producer`, `Resource` and `Consumer` are OWL Classes, while `producesResource` and `consumesResource` are object properties. The scenario is quite intuitive in that that each producer produces one or more  resources that is consumed by one or more consumers. Conversely, each  consumer can consume one or more resources. The ontology is populated with instances / individuals accordingly.

I would like to check if there exists a resource that is consumed by a consumer that is not produced by a Producer. What is an elegant way to get this information via a:

1. Query in SPARQL
2. SHACL Shapes graph (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negations are possible in SPARQL using the NOT BOUND filter or more easily in SPARQL 1.1 using MINUS:

```
SELECT ?resource WHERE
{
  ?resource a :Resource.

  ?consumer a :Consumer;
    ?consumer :consumesResource ?resource.

 MINUS {?producer a :Producer; :producesResource ?resource.}
}
```

You can also use `ASK` to get a boolean result but `SELECT` allows easier debugging to verify if your query is working correctly.

As SHACL allows integrating SPARQL queries, this answers your second question too but in that case it is easier to just use the SPARQL query on its own.

Comment: `FILTER NOT EXISTS` is the intended way to replace `OPTIONAL {...} FILTER(!BOUND(...))` way

Comment: @UninformedUser: Thanks for the correction! However in this specific case I assume MINUS works as well, because the triple patterns share a common variable, or is there an advantage to use FILTER NOT EXISTS in this case?